# Equipartition and correlations

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions

This question references [C.L.Henley's paper on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0407005). Page 3, section B: Effective free energy and correlations.

There is an ice polarization field $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})$, that has been coarse grained such that it is smoothly varying across the crystal.

The author argues the total free energy (completely entropic in origin) as a function of coarse-grained $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})$:

$$
F_{\mathrm{tot}} ( \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})) = \frac{T\kappa}{2v_\mathrm{cell}} \int d^3\mathbf{r} |\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})|^2  \tag{2.2}
$$
where $\kappa$ is some constant (stiffness), $v_\mathrm{cell}$ is the volume of unit cell, $T$ is temperature.

The Fourier transform of (2.2) gives 
$$
\tilde{F}_{\mathrm{tot}} = \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \frac{T\kappa}{2} |\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{k})|^2
$$

and it might also be relevant to note the probability distribution of the polarization field is a Gaussian distribution (ignoring the ice-rule constraints as in the paper for now):
$$
\text{Prob}( \{ \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) \} ) \propto \exp(- F_{\mathrm{tot}} ( \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}))/T) \tag{2.4}
$$

**The part that confuses me is:**
In the following statement (right after Eq 2.4 in the paper), the author writes:

> ..., so a naive use of equipartition would give
>   $$
> \left\langle P_\mu (-\mathbf{k})  P_\nu (\mathbf{k}) \right\rangle = \delta_{\mu\nu}/\kappa 
> $$

but I'm not sure how equipartition comes into play to give you correlations, nor the logic jump that the author seems to make here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equipartition of energy is [familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) as a result in classical statistical mechanics. It is usually applied to the case where a coordinate or momentum appears in the system Hamiltonian as a squared term, such as a kinetic energy component $p_x^2/2m$ or a harmonic term $\frac{1}{2}\kappa x^2$. Then, in calculating the canonical ensemble average at temperature $T$, involving the Boltzmann distribution, we can use the properties of Gaussian integrals to show
$$
\left\langle \tfrac{1}{2}\kappa x^2 \right\rangle
= \frac{\int dx  \, \tfrac{1}{2}\kappa x^2\, \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}\kappa x^2/k_BT)}{\int dx  \,  \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}\kappa x^2/k_BT)}
= \frac{1}{2}k_B T
$$
where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant. Hence we get an expression for the mean-square fluctuations
$$
\left\langle x^2 \right\rangle = \frac{k_BT}{\kappa}
$$

The same trick is often applied to coarse-grained *free energies*, $\mathcal{F}$, when they can be expressed as sums of quadratic terms in some generalized coordinate, or as a functional of a displacement field (squared, and integrated over space) or a similar integral involving the squared gradient of a field. Often the expression is only approximate, perhaps valid at long wavelengths. Examples include the fluctuations of interfaces (capillary waves) and director fluctuations in liquid crystals: the book *Principles of condensed matter physics* by PM Chaikin and TC Lubensky contains several of these examples. All that is required is an argument that the variables, or coordinates, are distributed according to a Boltzmann-like expression $\exp(-\mathcal{F}(\{Q_i\})/k_BT)$ where $\{Q_i\}$ is the set of coarse-grained coordinates, and that some of the coordinates of interest appear simply as quadratic terms in $\mathcal{F}$. The algebra then proceeds exactly as in the classical equipartition case.

In this case (and in many others) this becomes clear after taking a Fourier transform. There is a set of independent quadratic terms in the free energy, each term taking the form $\frac{1}{2}\kappa T |P_\alpha(\mathbf{k})|^2$, for each vector component $\alpha$, and for each wave-vector $\mathbf{k}$. A factor of $T$ has been included in the multiplying factor $\kappa T$, and the units have been chosen to make $k_B=1$, so the factor $k_BT$ will disappear from the final result. The equipartition formula then becomes
$$
\left\langle |P_\alpha(\mathbf{k})|^2 \right\rangle = 
\left\langle P_\alpha(\mathbf{k})P_\alpha(-\mathbf{k}) \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\kappa}
$$
and the fact that each component appears separately in the free energy means that any cross terms will vanish (hence the Kronecker delta).